# overload method with same generic parameter?

Tags: java, generics

I know that I can't do this:

```
public abstract class DTODomainTransformer<T, S> {

    public abstract S transform(T);

    public abstract T transform(S);

}
```

Because I get the compiler complaint:

```
Method transform(T) has the same erasure transform(Object) as another method in type Transformer<T,S>
```

I understand that is because both `T` and `S` could be extending same class. So doing this way i can tell him "No, they are not the same, so take it easy"

```
public interface Transformer<T extends AbstractDTO , S extends AbstractDomain> {

    public abstract S transform(T object);

    public abstract T transform(S object);

}
```

Then, my question is, is there any way to tell the compiler that `T` and `S` extend from different classes without telling which ones in concrete? I mean, in this last case, I've specified which classes had to be `T` and `S` (extending respectively). But what if I want it more generic and not specify them? I'd like to tell the compiler, "Hey, compiler, `T` and `S` are not the same! They are different classes. I don't know exactly which classes they are, but I'm sure that they are different".

Comment: No, there is no way to do that without giving explicit bounds.

Comment: How can you - programmer - assure the user of your class won't violate that rule, in case he/she uses raw type?

Comment: If it helps, you only have bind one of them. `<T extends Foo, S>`

Comment: You can't do that, because as you may know compiler will replace any T, S with Object if you won't specify any explicit bounds.

Comment: What I don't get, @RohitJain and  @MouseEvent, is that the compiler allows me to use `<T extends Integer, S>`, without any insurance that I won't later say `new Transformer<Integer, Integer>`.  In that case I don't get a compiler error until I try to do that ambiguous instantiation. And it works fine if I say `Transformer<Integer, String>`.  So why not accept `<T, S>` and wait until there's a problem to give the error? I'm not doubting you at all, but I'm definitely missing something.

Comment: @jas Generics do not exist at runtime. What you want can only be done at runtime. You want to restrict not to pass same type. But that can be identified only at runtime, when there is no existence of `T` and `S`.

Comment: You really ought to be using a different method name for each direction.

Comment: You could use Guavas [Converter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Converter.html) class as your parent class. It already contains what you need and you don't have to care about clashing methods, due to the different method names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not an obvious way. (Although you can build one, as I show below.)

This overload rule is due to a limitation of how the supertype (in this case, interface) that declares the overloads gets translated (by erasure) to bytecode.

If there's a generic parameter declared `T`, a method that uses `T` in its signature will have bytecode generated as the upper bound of `T`, for example

```
class Generic<T> {
    void work(T t) {}
}
```

will get erased to

```
class Generic {
    void work(Object t) {}
}
```

and

```
class Generic<T extends Number> {
    void work(T t) {}
}
```

will get erased to

```
class Generic {
    void work(Number t) {}
}
```

This is how the bounded example works, because the overloads erase differently.

```
public interface Transformer {
    public abstract AbstractDomain transform(AbstractDTO object);
    public abstract AbstractDTO transform(AbstractDomain object);
}
```

But without specific bounds, what erased bytecode should be generated for the overloaded methods?

So your `T` and `S` being *different on the subtype* is not what's important. What is important is the known declared bounds which get translated to erased bytecode for the supertype class.

---

A possible solution could use marker interfaces.

```
interface TransformT {}
interface TransformS {}
interface Transformable extends TransformT, TransformS {}

interface Transformer<T extends TransformT, S extends TransformS>
    T transform(S s);
    S transform(T t);
}

abstract class AbstractDTO implements Transformable {}
abstract class AbstractDomain implements Transformable {}

new SomeTransformerImpl<AbstractDTO, AbstractDomain>()
```

But I don't necessarily recommend doing this. It seems elaborate to me, although interesting. It depends on how complicated the actual class hierarchy is.

[What Louis suggested in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153921/overload-method-with-same-generic-parameter/29156559#comment46532150_29153921) is much simpler: give the methods different names.